# Using the Inverse Function Theorem in Implicit Differentiation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I'm given this problem as homework:

$y'(2x+y^3) = y$

with a clue: 'Use the inverse function theorem and find x as a function of y'

My questions include:

-Why can I use the inverse function theorem at all without additional assumptions?

I've gotten this far ignoring the first question:

$\frac{dx}{dy}y = ({y}^{-1})'y = 2x+y^3 $

Now can somewhat try to solve using linear form with respect to $y$ but am not sure how to differentiate $2x = y({y}^{-1}(x))$ if that is the meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are given:$$\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}\left(2x+y^3\right)&=y\\
\therefore 2x+y^3&=\frac{y}{\frac{dy}{dx}}\\
&=y\frac{dx}{dy}\text{ (using the inverse function theorem)}\\
\therefore\frac{dx}{dy}-\frac{2x}{y}&=y^2\text{ (rearranged after dividing through by }y\text{)}\\
\therefore \frac{1}{y^2}\frac{dx}{dy}-\frac{2x}{y^3}&=1\text{ (applied integrating factor of }\frac{1}{y^2}\text{)}\\
\therefore\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{x}{y^2}\right)&=1\tag{1}\\
\therefore\frac{x}{y^2}&=y+C\text{ (integrated w.r.t }y\text{)}\\
\therefore x&=y^3+Cy^2
\end{align}$$

---

Equation (1) was an insight since I noticed that:$$\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{x}{y^2}\right)=\frac{1}{y^2}\times\frac{dx}{dy}+x\times\frac{-2}{y^3}=\frac{1}{y^2}\frac{dx}{dy}-\frac{2x}{y^3}$$

---

**Rationale for using integrating factor method**

The standard form of a differential equation for applying the integrating factor is:$$\frac{dy}{dx}+p(x).y=q(x)$$I applied this to the inverse function to get:$$\frac{dx}{dy}+p(y).x=q(y)$$In this case we had:$$p(y)=-\frac{2}{y}$$$$q(y)=y^2$$and we obtain the integrating factor as:$$e^{\int-\frac{2}{y}dy}=e^{\ln y^{-2}}=y^{-2}=\frac{1}{y^2}$$